# Unable to start activity Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm new to Android Programming. I'm following the guide on Android Developers to get started with Android.
When trying to run simple Formular on the Emulator, the emulator shows

> "Unfortunately, My First App has stopped.",

where `MyFormular` is name of the App. The Problem is that I made new layout from layout resource file and tried to connect to the new loyout fror here

```
setContentView(R.layout.form_layout (the new layout is form_layout)
```

the new layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Please submit your details"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Confirm Password" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Terms &amp; Conditions"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="A Terms and Conditions can be used for both your "
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I agree"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Can&apos;t wait!Sign me up!"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainFormular.java

```
    package com.example.melisa.myformular;

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
     import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;

     public class MainFormular extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById  (R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_formular, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


 }
```

at android.app.Activity.performCreate  (activity_main_formular

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main_formular" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

logcat

Log is,

> 04-30 09:13:11.176 10175-10175/com.example.melisa.myformular I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10175 SIG: 9
>   04-30 10:03:45.336 10427-10427/com.example.melisa.myformular W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.melisa.myformular-1/lib/x86
>   04-30 10:03:47.008 10427-10427/com.example.melisa.myformular W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.melisa.myformular-1/lib/x86
>   04-30 10:03:47.112 10427-10427/com.example.melisa.myformular W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   04-30 10:03:47.128 10427-10427/com.example.melisa.myformular D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> 04-30 10:03:47.128 10427-10427/com.example.melisa.myformular E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.melisa.myformular, PID: 10427
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.melisa.myformular/com.example.melisa.myformular.MainFormular}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>      at com.example.melisa.myformular.MainFormular.onCreate(MainFormular.java:22)
>      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: add complete crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please remove this code and try to run your appliction......**

In your layout FloatingActionButton view is not there and you are trying to bind and make click event on that ......

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById  (R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

and this also......

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_formular, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Enjoy coding....

Comment: what can I do?give me a solution

Comment: this code It is made automatically every time when i try to create a new project